# Unable to get slack channel info when public channel changed to private

Tags: slack, slack-api

I created a public channel and changed it to private and invited my bot. Then with bot token I tried to access channel/group info using slack API  https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.info but resposne is "channel_not_found" when I used https://api.slack.com/methods/groups.info
API I got "method_not_supported_for_channel_type"

Do you have any Idea how to get channel info when it changed from public to private.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The old style API methods (like `channels.*` and `groups.*`) do not work for those kind of channels.

You need to use the newer `conversations.*` methods like `conversations.info` instead.